# Replace the HTML DOM completely with another DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I want to replace a HTML document in the browser with another HTML document or another DOM without changing the `document.location`.

Possible with JavaScript?

Comment: `document.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: @Barmar It does not work.

Comment: What about `document.body.innerHTML = "new contents"`?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't change a Window's `document` property by any other means than navigation (in case of an `open`ed Window or an `<iframe>`'s one from `about:blank`).

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#concept-document-window

Comment: What's about replacing both `<body>` and `<head>`? Will it work? What else need I take into account?

Comment: Even though you change everything in the document it won't change `window.document` to an other Document, which is what this question is asking for (for instance you can't change  from an HTMLDocument to an SVGDocument). Then if what you want is to change the *content* of the Document then sure you can remove any nodes inside it and replace it with any other (well, an HTMLDocument can only have as direct children a doctype node, head and body elements and comment nodes.

Comment: I assumeed the question is about replacing the contents of the document, not creating a new document object.

Comment: @Barmar it's not what's written in the question though...

Comment: @Kaiido And of course people always use the perfectly precise terminology when they ask questions about things they're not experts in.

Comment: They should yes. How far are you going otherwise? `document.getElementById("foo").remove()`? They asked **precisely** to replace a document with an other. This can't be done. They can however obviously remove all the nodes from said document and append all the nodes from an other **same-type** document, but the doc itself wouldn't have changed.